# Как вывести ключ словаря?

Tags: python

```
inp = str(input('Введите текст: '))
inp = inp.upper()
inp = list(inp)

def search():
    for i in abc:
        for k in inp[::]:
            if i == k:
                print(abc.keys)


search()
```

Мне нужно вывести на экран ключ словаря, соответствующий элементу списка, который есть в словаре.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Обычно словарь используют наоборот. По ключу ищут элемент. В этом его смысл. Может, вам просто поменять местами ключи и значения?

Comment: Я пробовал, а результат такой же был, я поэтому решил попробовать поменять местами

Comment: @POLTERGEIST, можно попробовать записывать два значения разом. Первое например `'Питон' : 'Python'`, а второе `'Python' : 'Питон'`

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, это решит ваш вопрос.
Когда в словаре находится ключ/значение, соответствующее искомому, возвращается пара `ключ, значение` в виде кортежа

```py
>>> a = {1: '2', '3': 4, '5': None}
>>> def search(d: dict, key):
...   lst = zip(a.keys(), a.values())
...   for k, v in lst:
...     if key in (k, v):
...       return k, v
...
>>> search(a, None)
('5', None)
>>> search(a, '3')
('3', 4)
```

Comment: Вместо `lst = zip(a.keys(), a.values())` можно написать просто `lst = a.items()`

Comment: @insolor спасибо, буду знать =)

Answer (score 0):

```
a = {"python": 10, "c": 100}

def search(a, b):
    c = list(a.values()).index(b)
    return list(a.keys())[c]
print(search(a, 100))
```